Is a parameterless constructor now always required by System.Text.Json?
I am updating a project to .NET 8 and some previously serializable/deserializable model classes are now throwing this error:

Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'MyModel' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.

The only way I appear to be able to stop the exception is to provide a parameterless constructor which I would prefer not to do.
UPDATE
The following code used to serialize/deserialize
void Main()
{
    RunTests();  // Call RunTests() or press Alt+Shift+T to initiate testing.
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public MyClass(int num, string characters)
    {
        Number = num;
        Text = characters;
    }

    // public MyClass() {} Test succeeds with parameterless ctor
}

[Fact] void Test_Xunit() 
{
    var mc = new MyClass(88, "foo");
    
    var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(mc);
    
    var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(s);
}



Do you not see the part that says "Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object"? Ergo, ctors with parameters are supported, provided the parameters' names match the incoming JSON's property names.

Can you show the code of said class? (Mainly the ctors and the properties)

Please share a [mcve], but your problem may be related to this: [Breaking change]: The System.Text.Json reflection-based deserializer is resolving all property metadata eagerly #37041 and Reflection-based deserializer resolves metadata eagerly.

If it is related to Reflection-based deserializer resolves metadata eagerly there may be other workarounds besides adding a parameterless constructor.  That's why it would be helpful to see a [mcve].

I see now too that parameter types must also match: a property of List<int> and a parameter of IEnumerable<int> will also fail.

Eventually came across this useful article.

As indicated by a comment above, you need to make sure the arguments to the constructor match the property names. Because the serializer uses the property names for creating the json, the deserializer needs to know which of these properties go to which constructor argument.
Thus, change your class like so:
public class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public MyClass(int number, string text) // argument names must match the property names
    {
        Number = number;
        Text = text;
    }
}

The comparison is case insensitive, so that you can use the standard naming conventions (which use capitalized names for properties but lowercase names for arguments).
As an alternative, you can add a parameterless constructor and let the deserializer use the property setters to initialize the object:
public class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public MyClass(int num, string characters)
    {
        Number = num;
        Text = characters;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}

This second approach is required if the property/argument types are complex. That means if your class uses a reference to another user-defined type, then you need to use the second approach.

The JsonSerializer requires a parameterless constructor to deserialize objects. Since MyClass only has a constructor that takes parameters, the deserialization process JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(s) will fail because it cannot instantiate MyClass without a public parameterless constructor. Its being public is essential.
As is well known, it can be done as follows:
public MyClass() {}

public MyClass(int num, string characters)
{
    Number = num;
    Text = characters;
}


"The JsonSerializer requires a parameterless constructor to deserialize objects." - This is completely untrue... take a look at the [JsonConstructor] attribute in both STJ and JSON.NET - and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability
